# GL11.loadIdentity() GL11.Translatef() and GL11.Rotatef()

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Im rendering models and textures using loadIdentity() before translating position and rotation of object.

Im trying to use Translatef and Rotatef in differend method to rotate my simple camera (one angle, character is always in the middle) and floor quad isnt moving or rotating. Im trying to manipulate of the view in infinite loop of the game:

```
while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
    Display.sync(60);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glTranslatef(test, 0, 0);
    drawScene();
    processKeyboard();
    Display.update();

}

drawScene() {    
    glLoadIdentity();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,animationTexture.getTextureID());
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(ax, ay, az);
    glRotatef(rotatex, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(rotatey, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(rotatez, 0, 0, 1);
    glScalef(scalex, scaley, scalez);
    GL11.glCallList(this.objectlist);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
```

Is there a way that i can edit this code to get my simple view edit working, or i must find other way to set model position?

EDIT: Question Closed... I just found the simplest solution in the world. I just needed to remove glLoadIdentity() command from every drawing class in project, when i use only PushMatrix it is resetting view parameters only for commands between Push and Pop Matrix commands.

Comment: Hi Bushi, it would be preferred if you could post your solution as an answer instead of an edit, then you can mark the question as answered. Thanks!